# Find the particular equation of $U_x+xU=x^3+3xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

He there
I’m working on a PDE question but I’m having trouble finding particular answer of this equation:

$$U_x+xU=x^3+3xy$$

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti yeah sorry

Comment: @Negar. Do you know how to solve this ODE : $\frac{dU}{dx}+xU=x^3+3cx$ ?

Comment: Something to note: when all of the derivatives are in terms of the same independent variable, you can treat the equation as an ODE. So, as JJacquelin points out, you can solve this with normal ODE techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general solution method you can use for problems like this, often called the "integration factor" method.

The idea is that if we can get our equation in the form $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}[f(x,y)U(x,y)] = g(x,y)$ then we can integrate on both sides to find the solution. So, we want to manipulate the left-hand side of our equation into something of the form $fU_x + f_xU$.

In our current equation, the left-hand side is $U_x + xU$, so we need to multiply through by our $f$ to get the form we want. If we do this, the coefficient on the $U$ is $xf$, which we want to be equal to $f_x$.

So now we can solve the separable equation $f_x = xf$ to get our function $f$:
$$f_x = xf \to \dfrac{f_x}{f} = x \to \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}[\ln f] = x \to f = e^{\int x dx}$$

In the future if you have to solve equations like this you can skip directly to this form, but I thought it would be good to show the reasoning behind where this form comes from. Note that you do not have to include an integration constant because we are only looking for one solution for $f$, so we can just use $f = e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$.

Now, we can multiply both sides by $f$ as planned, yielding $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}U_x + xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}U = x^3e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} + 3xye^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$, which we can rewrite as $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} [e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} U] = x^3e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} + 3xye^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$.

Now let's integrate both sides with respect to $x$. On the left-hand side we can simply use the fundamental theorem of calculus to get $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}U + h_1(y)$. To integrate the right-hand side, let $u = \dfrac{x^2}{2}$:
$$\int x^3e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} + 3xye^{\frac{x^2}{2}} dx = \int (2u + 3y)e^u du = \int (2u + 3y) d(e^u) = (2u + 3y)e^u - \int 2e^u du = (x^2 + 3y - 2)e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} + h_2(y).$$

Notice that here our arbitrary "constants" are actually functions of $y$, because any function of $y$ will vanish when we take a partial derivative with respect to $x$.

So now we have that $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}U + h_1(y) = (x^2 + 3y - 2)e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} + h_2(y)$. Letting $h(y) = h_2(y) - h_1(y)$ we can combine the two integration constants, and then we can divide both sides by $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ without restrictions because it is never zero, giving us $U(x,y) = x^2 + 3y - 2 + h(y)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ as our general solution.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration.